# bootstrap nav bar custom elements for mobile

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

what is the best way to add an extra element to a bootstrap nav bar when its stacked vertically for mobile users.

For example would like to add `<li>New Tab</li>` to:

```
 <nav id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>Home</a></li>
        <li>Forum</a></li>
        <li>About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: so you want to add the <li>New Tab</li> inside the ul, right?

Comment: yes, but only when the nav bar is in the mobile version state (vertically stacked)

Comment: so you mean to add it when the user is in mobile, right?

Comment: i think bootstrap works off the screen width, so when this becomes to small it converts the nav bar to vertically listed